# How can I plot a pandas dataframe as a scatter graph? I think I may have messed up the indexing and can't add a new index?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot my steps as a scatter graph and then eventually add a trend line.
I managed to get it to work with df.plot() but it is a line chart.

The following is the code I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data_file = pd.read_csv('CSV/stepsgyro.csv')

# print(data_file.head())

# put in the correct data types
data_file = data_file.astype({"steps": int})
pd.to_datetime(data_file['date'])

# makes the date definitely the index at the bottom
data_file.set_index(['date'], inplace=True)

# sorts the data frame by the index
data_file.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
# data_file.columns.values[1] = 'date'

# plot the raw steps data
# data_file.plot()
plt.scatter(data_file.date, data_file.steps)
plt.title('Daily Steps')
plt.grid(alpha=0.3)
plt.show()

plt.close('all')

# plot the cumulative steps data
data_file = data_file.cumsum()
data_file.plot()
plt.title('Cumulative Daily Steps')
plt.grid(alpha=0.3)
plt.show()

plt.close('all')
```

and here is a screenshot of what it's looking like on my IDE:
[image: pic]

any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have set the index to be the "date" column. From that moment on, there is no "date" column anymore, hence `data_file.date` fails.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest hmm, I did that because I wanted to sort the dataframe from index, is there any way to use the index as the scatter x value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have set the index to be the "date" column. From that moment on, there is no "date" column anymore, hence `data_file.date` fails.

Two options:

1. Don't set the index. Sorting doesn't seem to be needed anyways.
2. Plot the index, `plt.scatter(data_file.index, data_file.steps)`

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out just by looking at your example why you are getting that error.  However, I can offer a quick and easy solution to plotting your data:

```
data_file.plot(marker='.', linestyle='none')
```

Comment: Thanks :) that works,although not sure if I can then add a trend line :p we shall see

Answer (score 1):

You can use `df.plot(kind='scatter')` to avoid the line chart.